# How to generate cumulative sum of changes of a variable in a group across time

Tags: stata

I need to generate the variable `sum` which cumulatively adds up the changes in `TA_envi_tot` across reporter-partner pairs and years. `reporter_iso` and `partner_iso` are string variables. Meanwhile, `id` is generated by `egen id =group(reporter_iso partner_iso)`.

I tried these codes but I don't get to generate the values in the "sum" column below:

```
bysort id (year): gen sum=TA_envi_tot[_n] + TA_envi_tot[_n+1] if TA_envi_tot[_n]!=TA_envi_tot[_n-1]
bysort id (year): replace sum = sum[_n-1] if missing(sum)

id  reporter_iso    partner_iso year    TA_envi_tot sum
3271    ATG              DEU    1981           0     0
3271    ATG              DEU    1982           0     0
3271    ATG              DEU    1983           0     0
3271    ATG              DEU    1984          36    36
3271    ATG              DEU    1985          36    36
3271    ATG              DEU    1986          36    36
3271    ATG              DEU    1987          67    103
3271    ATG              DEU    1988          67    103
3271    ATG              DEU    1989          67    103
4217    BDI              BEL    1981           3    3
4217    BDI              BEL    1982           3    3
4217    BDI              BEL    1983           3    3
4217    BDI              BEL    1984          35    38
4217    BDI              BEL    1985          35    38
4217    BDI              BEL    1986          35    38
4217    BDI              BEL    1987          35    38
4217    BDI              BEL    1988          36    74
4217    BDI              BEL    1989          36    74
4217    BDI              BEL    1990          36    74
```

Comment: There is no `TA_envi_sum` in the data example. Note that your `id` groups all (BDI, BEL) together but (BEL, BDI) remains distinct. Is that what you want? Why does `TA_envi_tot` show that behaviour any way?

Comment: Problem may arise from confusion over variable names.

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks a lot. The code works well. Yes, (BDI, BEL) and (BEL, BDI) should be distinct as these are country pairs involved in free trade agreements (FTA). TA_envi_tot is the number of environment-related provisions in FTAs. So every time a country enters into a new FTA which includes the same partner then TA_envi_tot adds up.

Comment: Good, and pleased if this was helpful, but your question is still not clear: (1) we can't test your code mentioning `TA_envi_sum` because it is not a variable in the data example; (2) you don't say what you did get.  If your question hinges on getting a variable name wrong, it's unlikely to be of use to anyone else and on that ground should be deleted.

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks again for your comments. I already revised my code above from TA_envi_sum to TA_envi_tot. Using your code below, I was able to generate the "sum" variable in the sample dataset. Hope this addresses your comments. Glad to clarify more.

Comment: The larger point is that the aim here on SO is to buld up an inventory of answered questions that will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clear 

input id  str3 (reporter_iso    partner_iso) year    TA_envi_tot sum
3271    ATG              DEU    1981           0     0
3271    ATG              DEU    1982           0     0
3271    ATG              DEU    1983           0     0
3271    ATG              DEU    1984          36    36
3271    ATG              DEU    1985          36    36
3271    ATG              DEU    1986          36    36
3271    ATG              DEU    1987          67    103
3271    ATG              DEU    1988          67    103
3271    ATG              DEU    1989          67    103
4217    BDI              BEL    1981           3    3
4217    BDI              BEL    1982           3    3
4217    BDI              BEL    1983           3    3
4217    BDI              BEL    1984          35    38
4217    BDI              BEL    1985          35    38
4217    BDI              BEL    1986          35    38
4217    BDI              BEL    1987          35    38
4217    BDI              BEL    1988          36    74
4217    BDI              BEL    1989          36    74
4217    BDI              BEL    1990          36    74
end 

bysort id (year) : gen wanted = sum(TA_envi_tot * (TA_envi_tot != TA_envi_tot[_n-1]))
```